# Python: List index out of range, don't know why

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to iterate through a matrix and check for the number of cells touching the current cell that have a value of 1. I'm getting an out of bounds exception and I'm not sure why.

```
for x in range(0,ROWS):
    for y in range(0,COLS):

        #get neighbors
        neighbors = []
        if x!=0 & y!=COLS:
            neighbors.append([x-1,y+1])
        if y!=COLS:
            neighbors.append([x,y+1])
        if x!=ROWS & y!=COLS:
            neighbors.append([x+1,y+1])
        if x!=0:
            neighbors.append([x-1,y])
        if x!=ROWS:
            neighbors.append([x+1,y])
        if x!=0 & y!=0:
            neighbors.append([x-1,y-1])
        if y!=0:
            neighbors.append([x,y-1])
        if x!=ROWS & y!=0:
            neighbors.append([x+1,y-1])

        #determine # of living neighbors
        alive = []
        for i in neighbors:
            if matrix[i[0]][i[1]] == 1:
                alive.append(i)
```

I'm getting the error

> IndexError: list index out of range

at this line `if matrix[i[0]][i[1]] == 1:`

Why is this out of range and how should I fix it?

Comment: `if cells[i[0]][i[1]] == 1:` isn't present in your code. Assuming you meant `if matrix[i[0]][i[1]] == 1:` could you be more specific about what the values in `matrix` are before this line?

Comment: I renamed cells to matrix when I copypasted into stackoverflow to make it clearer what it was, I just forgot to rename it at the bottom of the post too. I've edited my post, should make more sense now. Before this, the matrix is filled with either 0's or 1's, distributed randomly.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you give the full stack trace, rather than just the exception.

Comment: `if x!=ROWS & y!=0: neighbors.append([x+1,y-1])` if x here is ROWS-1 (the last one as the range is defined). adding one to the x would give a index error later. Assuming ROWS\COLS is the real number of rows\cols.

Comment: OP: I mentioned this in my answer, but generally matrixes are left-to-right, top-to-bottom. Though you don't seem to be suffering that problem here, in most instances you want to do `for x in range(COLS); for y in range(ROWS)` and `matrix[y][x]`

Comment: @M4rtini good catch. I think this and the bitwise AND will fix OP's issue. To be explicit, the lines should read `if x < ROWS-1 and y < COLS-1` (but for the swap in `ROWS` and `COLS` I mentioned.

Comment: Ok it is working! Replacing ROWS/COLS with ROWS-1/COLS-1 did the trick! Update your answer and I'll mark it as an accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `&`. This is a bit-wise AND, not a logical AND. In Python, you just use `and`. For example:

```
if x!=0 and y!=COLS:
    neighbors.append([x-1,y+1])
```

However the real reason why using the bit-wise AND causes a problem is order of operations - it has a higher precedence!

```
>>> 1 != 2 & 3 != 3
True
>>> (1 != 2) & (3 != 3)
False
>>> 1 != (2 & 3) != 3
True
```

So even though your logic looks right, order of operations means that your code's actual behavior is drastically different than what you were expecting.

The other issue with your code is that you are checking if `x` and `y` are equal to `ROWS` and `COLS`, rather than if they are equal to `ROWS-1` and `COLS-1`, which are the true boundary conditions.

Comment: Good catch! You posted your answer right as I was editing mine in :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error after replacing the &, with 'and'

Comment: @Petefic M4rtini found one more error in the comments on your question

Comment: @AdamSmith Oh yeah, a simple off-by-one error. I've added that into my answer, too.

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT: I THINK I FOUND IT***

Upon further inspection of your code, I found that you're using `if x!=0 & y!=0`. This is bit-wise AND not logical AND, so it's not going to give you the result you want. Use `and` instead of `&` and see if your problem goes away.

I would refactor this slightly to make it easier to read.

```
for loc_x in range(ROWS):
    for loc_y in range(COLS): # btw shouldn't ROWS/COLS be flipped?
                              # if your matrix isn't square this could be why
        x_values = [loc_x]
        if loc_x < ROWS: x_values.append(loc_x+1)
        if loc_x > 0: x_values.append(loc_x-1)
        y_values = [loc_y]
        if loc_y < COLS: y_values.append(loc_y+1)
        if loc_y > 0: y_values.append(loc_y-1)
        neighbors = [(x,y) for x in x_values for y in y_values if (x,y) != (loc_x,loc_y)]

        alive = [matrix[n[0]][n[1]] for n in neighbors if matrix[n[0]][n[1]]==1]
```

Try running this with your code and see if it doesn't solve the issue. If not, you may need to test further. For instance, wrap the `alive` definition in `try/except` tags that will give a better traceback.

```
try:
    alive = ...
except IndexError:
    print("Location: {},{}\nneighbors: {}\nROWS:{}\nCOLS:{}".format(x_loc,y_loc, neighbors,ROWS,COLS))
    raise
```

As an aside, I've solved this problem before by creating objects that held the linked information and going top-to-bottom left-to-right and having each check the field to its right and below it. E.g.:

```
class Field(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,value):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.value = value
        self.neighbors = neighbors

class Matrix(list):
    def __init__(self,size):
        self.ROWS,self.COLS = map(int,size.lower().split("x"))
        for y in range(ROWS):
            self.append([Field(x,y,random.randint(0,1)) for x in range(COLS)])
        self.plot()
    def plot(self):
        for row in self:
            for col in row:
                try:
                    self[row][col].neighbors.append(self[row+1][col])
                    self[row+1][col].neighbors.append(self[row][col])
                except IndexError: pass
                try:
                    self[row][col].neighbors.append(self[row][col+1])
                    self[row][col+1].neighbors.append(self[row][col])
                except IndexError: pass
```

Of course this doesn't take care of diagonals. I'm pretty sure you can figure out how to manage those, though!!